# Counting working days between two dates in data table using calendar table

Tags: sql, date, calendar

I have a data table, which consist of 4 dates per string:
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cttY.png)
Also I have calendar table with holidays and weekends for my location.
[calendar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcMFi.png)

What I need is to count number of working days for following pairs in data table:

- **task_work_end_date** and **task_got_to_work_date**
- **task_got_to_work_date** and **task_assigned_date**

I have tried following select, but it would always show 1 working day, because I'm putting calendar_date in front:

```
select data_table.*, days.work_days 
from data_table
left join (
    select calendar_date, count(calendar_date) as work_days
    from calendar_table
    where type_of_day IN ('workday', 'workday shortened')
    group by calendar_date ) days
ON days.calendar_date between task_assigned_date and task_got_to_work_date
```

Please advise on SQL to achieve correct joining those tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution worked perfectly for me in POSTGRES:

```
table example
join
calendar table ON tsrange(task_assigned_date, task_got_to_work_date)&&tsrange(calendar.start_time, calendar.end_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a left join, you need to change how you are grouping.  You can list the actual columns in data_table in the `group by` and the `select` as well.

```
select data_table.*, count(days.calendar_date)
from data_table
left join calendar_table days
   ON days.calendar_date between task_assigned_date and task_got_to_work_date
      and type_of_day IN ('workday', 'workday shortened')
group by data_table.*
```

Another option would be to outer apply and get the count this way:

```
select data_table.*, days.work_days 
from data_table
outer apply (
    select count(calendar_date) as work_days
    from calendar_table
    where type_of_day IN ('workday', 'workday shortened')
      and calendar_date between task_assigned_date and task_got_to_work_date) days
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL server then use `OUTER APPLY` as follows:

```
select d.*, days.work_days 
from data_table d
outer apply (
    select count(calendar_date) as work_days
    from calendar_table c
    where c.type_of_day IN ('workday', 'workday shortened') 
      and c.calendar_date between d.task_assigned_date and d.task_got_to_work_date) days
```

Answer (score 0):

A lateral join is definitely one way to solve the problem (that is the `apply` syntax in the other answers).

A more generic answer is simply a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*, 
       (select count(*)
        from calendar_table c
        where c.type_of_day in ('workday', 'workday shortened') and
              c.calendar_date between d.task_assigned_date and d.task_got_to_work_datework_days 
       ) as work_days
from data_table d;
```

Note:  If performance is an issue, there may be other approaches.  If that is the case, accept one of the answers here and ask a *new* question.